# Is there a connection leak while using Grails with Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, grails

I Just followed the following link to build a sample app using grails and Mongo db.

http://etcpe9.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/beginning-grails-2-0-with-mongodb/

But each time I create a new person I can see following in mongod shell 
XX connection now open .

I am not sure if this means a connection leak ?

```
Thu Feb 21 21:04:06 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50526 #22
 (1 connection now open)
Thu Feb 21 21:04:27 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50527 #23
 (2 connections now open)
Thu Feb 21 21:04:27 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50528 #24
 (3 connections now open)
Thu Feb 21 21:04:36 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50531 #25
 (4 connections now open)
Thu Feb 21 21:04:36 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50532 #26
 (5 connections now open)
Thu Feb 21 21:04:48 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50533 #27
 (6 connections now open)
Thu Feb 21 21:04:53 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50534 #28
 (7 connections now open)
Thu Feb 21 21:04:59 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50535 #29
 (8 connections now open)
Thu Feb 21 21:05:04 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50536 #30
 (9 connections now open)
Thu Feb 21 21:05:10 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50537 #31
 (10 connections now open)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is the mongodb driver maintaining a connection pool so it can reuse connections.

Comment: True, after a few connections it stops increasing .